# When Magento upgrade 2.2.1 to 2.4.3 - Unable to apply data patch: module Magento_Tax

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.3, setup-upgrade, data-patch

How to fix the below Error when magento upgrade 2.2.1 to 2.4.3.

When I have run setup upgrade command then showing error.

> Unable to apply data patch
> Magento\Tax\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateTaxRegionId for module Magento_Tax.
> Original exception message: Code already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a patch is run, Magento adds it into the `patch_list` table, so, the next time when you run `setup:upgrade`, it checks if that patch is present in that table, then it skips the patch. So, what you can do, is just manually add `\Magento\Tax\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateTaxRegionId` into the table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this issue occurred during `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

look like you already applied patch earlier and upgrade want to apply it again so, simply you can delete this file

> /vendor/magento/module-tax/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateTaxRegionId.php

or try to upgrade with latest version 2.4.3-p2 this may also fix problem

**Update**

---

If you were upgrading to Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods)/Magneto Open Source version 2.3.5, upgrade to version 2.3.5-p1. Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods)/Magento Open Source version 2.3.5-p1 replaces 2.3.5.

If you were upgrading to Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods)/Magento Open Source version 2.3.4-p1, upgrade to version 2.3.4-p2. Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods)/Magneto Open Source version 2.3.4-p2 replaces version 2.3.4-p1.

Comment: Yes, I have already deleted this file and work perfect but I need proper solution.

Comment: then I guess you need to upgrade in latest version 2.4.3-p2  instead of 2.4.3

Comment: Yes, But First I will done all issues in 2.4.3 then upgrade in 2.4.3-p2. Thanks @Gohil Rajesh

Comment: welcome @BhaveshGodhani

Comment: Please do not advise people to delete or modify core code, this is never recommended

Comment: @DanStaver Yes, You are right but error is "Code already exists." that mean they already applied patch and now trying to upgrade magento version so, sometime we need to do dirty our hand

Comment: also I provided proper solution to upgrade to latest version too. anyway thanx for attention

Comment: @GohilRajesh I have upgrade the Magento2.4.3-p1 still fetch the same issues it's not fixed. May be when install fresh Magento2.4.3-p1 than it's not show the error but upgrade magento version then show this error.

Comment: sorry, then no idea about why it's still not working.